# Populate p:selectOneMenu based on another p:selectOneMenu in each row of a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu

I have a `<p:dataTable>` with lazy load. In two of the columns, there is a `<p:selectOneMenu>` in each of them.

The first column holds a list of countries and the second one holds a list of states from a database.

I want the second menu (the one that contains a list of states) to show only those states in **each row** of the data table which correspond to the country in the first menu in **each row** of the data table.

During edit mode, when a country in its menu is changed, the states corresponding to that country should be populated in its menu in that current row.

How to load such lists of states that correspond to their countries in each row of the data table?

---

These two columns in the data table are left incomplete, since I don't have a precise idea about how to achieve this.

```
<p:column>
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.state.country.countryName}"/>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{row.state.country}">
                <f:selectItems var="country"
                               value="#{cityBean.selectedCountries}"
                               itemLabel="#{country.countryName}"
                               itemValue="#{country}"/>

                <p:ajax update="states" listener="#{cityBean.getStates}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.state.stateName}"/>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="states">

                <f:selectItems var="state"
                               value="#{cityBean.selectedStates}"
                               itemLabel="#{state.stateName}"
                               itemValue="#{state}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

`cityBean.selectedCountries` retrieves all the countries which is necessary but `cityBean.selectedStates` also retrieves all the states from the database which is unnecessary and should be modified to retrieve only those states which correspond to its country in another menu.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Here's where you take advantage of your auxiliary class. Your `countryId` is not located into your managed bean directly, but in your auxiliary class (remember the list you use to build the table is composed by this auxiliaries). Then you have the ajax event listener (this one goes in the MB) which will receive the row that was changed. The MB just takes the auxiliary object which was changed (its `countryId`) and loads its updated state list which goes INTO the auxiliar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whilst your initial solution works, it's in fact inefficient. This approach basically requires the entire object graph of the `Country` and `State` tables (even with circular references) to be fully loaded in Java's memory per JSF view or session even though when you simultaneously use only e.g. 5 of 150 countries (and thus theoretically 5 state lists would have been sufficient instead of 150 state lists).

I don't have full insight into your functional and technical requirements. Perhaps you're actually simultaneously using all of those 150 countries. Perhaps you've many pages where *all* (at least, "many") countries and states are needed. Perhaps you've state of art server hardware with plenty of memory so that all countries and states can effortlessly be duplicated over all JSF views and HTTP sessions in memory.

If that's not the case, then it would be beneficial to *not* eagerly fetch the state list of every single country (i.e. `@OneToMany(fetch=LAZY)` should be used on `Country#states` and `State#cities`). Given that country and state lists are (likely) static data which changes very few times in a year, at least sufficient to be changed on a per-deploy basis only, it's better to just store them in an application scoped bean which is reused across all views and sessions instead of being duplicated in every JSF view or HTTP session.

Before continuing to the answer, I'd like to remark that there's a logic error in your code. Given the fact that you're editing a list of cities, and thus `#{row}` is essentially `#{city}`, it's strange that you reference the country via the state as in `#{city.state.country}` in the dropdown input value. Whilst that may work for displaying, that wouldn't work for editing/saving. Basically, you're here changing the country on a per-state basis instead of on a per-city basis. The currently selected state would get the new country instead of the currently iterated city. This change would get reflected in all cities of this state!

This is indeed not trivial if you'd like to continue with this data model. Ideally, you'd like to have a separate (virtual) `Country` property on `City` so that the changes doesn't affect the city's `State` property. You could make it just `@Transient` so that JPA doesn't consider it as a `@Column` as by default.

```
@Transient // This is already saved via City#state#country.
private Country country;

public Country getCountry() {
    return (country == null && state != null) ? state.getCountry() : country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) { 
    this.country = country;

    if (country == null) {
        state = null;
    }
}
```

All in all, you should ultimately have this (irrelevant/default/obvious attributes omitted for brevity):

```
<p:dataTable value="#{someViewScopedBean.cities}" var="city">
    ...
    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{city.country}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{applicationBean.countries}" />
        <p:ajax update="state" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    ...
    <p:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{city.state}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{applicationBean.getStates(city.country)}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

With an `#{applicationBean}` something like this:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationBean {

    private List<Country> countries;
    private Map<Country, List<State>> statesByCountry;

    @EJB
    private CountryService countryService;

    @EJB
    private StateService stateService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        countries = countryService.list();
        statesByCountry = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public List<State> getStates(Country country) {
        List<State> states = statesByCountry.get(country);

        if (states == null) {
            states = stateService.getByCountry(country);
            statesByCountry.put(country, states);
        }

        return states;
    }

}
```

*(this is the lazy loading approach; you could also immediately fetch them all in `@PostConstruct`, just see what's better for you)*

Comment: Complete example / explanation, worked great. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, I generally don't end bounties util grace period for no precise reason(s). Is there anything irritating I'm doing? :)

Comment: You're welcome. No problem as to bounty. The longer the question stays in the "featured" list, the more chance you have on some upvotes in the end so that you can earn the spent reputation back.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is quite simple. There is no need to code any further. In the state menu, the following,

```
<f:selectItems var="state" value="#{cityManagedBean.selectedStates}" 
               itemLabel="#{state.stateName}" itemValue="#{state}" 
               itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
```

is just required to be modified as follows.

```
<f:selectItems var="state" value="#{row.state.country.stateTableSet}" 
               itemLabel="#{state.stateName}" itemValue="#{state}" 
               itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
```

Since, the entity object (`row` in this case) contains an embedded object of `state` which in turn, contains an object of `country` which finally contains a list of states  **corresponding to that `country` only** as obvious.

So that

```
cityManagedBean.selectedStates
```

an extra managed bean method is now not required at all and needed to be modified as

```
row.state.country.stateTableSet
```

Where `stateTableSet` is a `Set<StateTable>` that contains a list of objects of the `StateTable` entity.

---

Also, `listener` in `<p:ajax>` is not required anymore. It should simply look like the following.

```
<p:ajax update="cmbStateMenu"/>
```

It is there just for the purpose of updating the state menu, when an item (country) is selected in the country menu.

---

The code in question should now look like the following.

```
<p:column id="country" headerText="Country" resizable="true" sortBy="#{row.state.country.countryName}" filterBy="#{row.state.country.countryName}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterMaxLength="45">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputLink value="Country.jsf">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.state.country.countryName}"/>
                <f:param name="id" value="#{row.state.country.countryId}"/>
            </h:outputLink>                                                                                
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" converter="#{countryConverter}" value="#{row.state.country}" label="Country" required="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" effect="fold" rendered="true" editable="false" style="width:100%;">
                <f:selectItems var="country" value="#{cityManagedBean.selectedCountries}" itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
                <p:ajax update="cmbStateMenu"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

<p:column id="state" headerText="State" resizable="false" sortBy="#{row.state.stateName}" filterBy="#{row.state.stateName}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterMaxLength="45">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputLink value="State.jsf">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.state.stateName}"/>
                <f:param name="id" value="#{row.state.stateId}"/>
            </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbStateMenu" converter="#{stateConverter}" value="#{row.state}" label="State" required="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" effect="fold" rendered="true" editable="false" style="width:100%;">
                <f:selectItems var="state" value="#{row.state.country.stateTableSet}" itemLabel="#{state.stateName}" itemValue="#{state}" itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

<sub>Apology : I didn't mention in the question that I was retrieving a list of cities.</sub>

Comment: Whilst this may work, this is essentially data duplication and therefore memory-inefficient.

Comment: May I know another precise way?

Comment: JPA cache + parameterized getter in an application scoped bean (or if you're using CDI, a `@Produces` method; not sure what the Spring equivalent is to that as I don't do Spring)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the state list based on the Country selected. You need a valueChangeListener for that.

Try this ( I've put both select one menu's in the same column for now)

In your xhtml

```
<p:column id="state" headerText="State" sortBy="#{row.state.stateName}" filterBy="#{row.state.stateName}">
<p:cellEditor>  
        <f:facet name="output">  
        <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputLink value="State.jsf">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.state.stateName}"/>
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{row.state.stateId}"/>
                    </h:outputLink>
            </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">  
        <h:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" style="width:100px" value="#{row.state.country}" converterMessage="Error message." label="Country" valueChangeListener = "#{countryController.handleCountrySelect}" immediate="true"  converter="#{countryConverter}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel = "Select" itemValue="#{null}" /> 
            <f:selectItems var="country" value="#{cityManagedBean.selectedCountries}" itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" itemValue="#{country}"/>
            <p:ajax update="cmbStateMenu" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu style="width:100px" value="#{row.state}" valueChangeListener = "#{stateController.handleStateSelect}" immediate="false" id="cmbStateMenu"  converter = "#{stateConverter}">

             <f:selectItems var="state" value="#{row.state.country.stateTableSet}" itemLabel="#{state.stateName}" itemValue="#{state}" itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
            <p:ajax update="@this" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>  
    </p:cellEditor>
```

in you controller

```
  public void handleCountrySelect( ValueChangeEvent event )
{
    setStates( ( ( Country) event.getNewValue() ) );
}
```

Comment: In this case, the answer I posted does the expected function but the EL expression like `row.state.country.stateTableSet` (`java.util.Set ` was changed to `java.util.List` long after this post) must be omitted/removed in its entirely, since it is very costly. In case of remote EJBs, it requires a fully **eagerly** loaded relationship or a costly collection fetch in JPA for it to function properly which is a worst thing to implement and should **not** be used util and unless it is **absolutely** necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.