# Using JSF, how can I bind form values to an object but also manipulate those values in the form's (separate) controller?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, selectonemenu

Let's say I want to create a country/state picker and use it to manage the pulldown menus in a form.  Ideally, I'd like to bind the values of these menus to the location Object I'm trying to manage.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="countryMenu" value=#{controller.location.country}>
    <f:ajax listener="{controller.locationPicker.updateStates}"
            execute="stateMenu cityInput"/>
    <h:selectItems value=#{controller.locationPicker.countries}/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="stateMenu" value=#{controller.location.state}>
    <f:ajax listener="{controller.locationPicker.updateCities}" execute="cityInput"/>
    <h:selectItems value=#{controller.locationPicker.states}/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText id="cityInput" value=#{controller.location.city} 
             rendered=#{not empty controller.location.state"/>
```

```
public class LocationPicker {
.
.
    public void updateStates(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        List<String> selectedCountries = getSelectionsFromEvent(event);
        states = getStatesFromCountries(selectedCountries);
        cities = getCitiesFromStates(states);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the only way to get the `location.country` or `location.state` values within the `locationPicker`, is to use the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` to get the value.  This doesn't seem like the right approach, though, considering I have to cache all of these values within the `locationPicker` because there are other form elements which depend on these values and each `AjaxBehaviorEvent` only has the value for the component it's fire on.

It would be SO MUCH EASIER to just bind the menu values/selectItems to one object (the `locationPicker`). Then, when submitting the form, copy the locationPicker values to the location object.  I'm trying to avoid that though!

Anyone have any recommendations on how to make this work?

Comment: Can't you get those selected value of `<h:selectOneMenu>`s  in the associated backing bean simply by adding properties of the desired types (`String` apparently) and binding the `value` attribute of `<h:selectOneMenu>`s to those properties? You are apparently sending those selected values to a different bean `location` (not `locationPicker`) as can be seen by `value=#{location.country}` and `value=#{location.state}` in the respective `<h:selectOneMenu>`s.

Comment: @Tiny Well, that's the point of my question.  I don't want to add Strings to the LocationPicker just to maintain the menu values, then have to copy them to the Location object later.  NOTE: I just added in a controller for clarity.  Location and LocationPicker are non-JSF managed classes.  Let's say that Location is a database Entity and LocationPicker is a helper class which manages country/state/city combinations.

Comment: @Tiny The reason I'm trying to make these as independent as possible is because the LocationPicker could be used by something else.  Let's say a SearchFilter class that allowed you to choose 1 or more countries/states/cities.  It isn't always just linked to a Location object.

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613029/populate-pselectonemenu-based-on-another-pselectonemenu-in-each-row-of-a-pdat Question is a bit different, but the answer seems to cover all your needs.

Comment: @BalusC Hmm, not really.  Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my original question, but I don't want to just access the value within the controller...I want to somehow manipulate that value within the controller but still keep that value bound to my Entity.  For example, if I have a state selected and then I change the country, the list of stateMenu selectItems changes making the selected state invalid.  I'd want the stateMenu value to be set to "" or null.  Then, because the select state value is "", the cityInput field should no longer be rendered.

Comment: @BalusC Just an aside: I'm doing all of this work to a) try to keep my Entity object (with its own Location object) separate from the LocationPicker's logic and b) allow me to directly attach these form field values to the Entity so that I don't have to copy them over later.  Do u think this is silly or is it a reasonable design objective achievable with JSF?