# Resetting child p:selectOneMenus inside a p:dataTable to empty, when a labelled item in their parent list is selected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

There are three tables in MySQL database, `category`, `sub_category` and `brand` (manufacturer) where `category` is a parent of the rest i.e. `sub_category` and `brand`. I hope, the relationship between menus can be clearer based on the table relationships.

All of three `<p:selectOneMenu>`s are placed inside a `<p:dataTable>` in three respective columns as identified by `<p:column>`. I am ignoring `<p:column>`, `<p:cellEditor>`, `<f:facet name="output">`, `<f:facet name="input">`, `<p:rowEditor>` and all such nuisances for brevity.

<sub>`row` corresponds to a JPA managed entity which is `product` in this case as specified by `var="row"` in the `<p:dataTable>` associated.</sub>

**This is the actual question mark :** When an item (the first one) with a `null` value in the `categoryList` (parent) is selected, its child lists `subCategoryList` and `brandList` should be rest to empty.

Category List:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="categoryList"
                 value="#{row.category}"
                 required="#{param['javax.faces.source'] ne component.clientId}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select"
                  itemValue="#{null}"/>
    <!-- When this item is selected, its children below should be reset to empty. -->

    <f:selectItems var="category"
                   value="#{productManagedBean.categories}"
                   itemLabel="Select"
                   itemValue="#{category}"/>

    <p:ajax update="subCategoryList brandList"/>
    <!-- The listener functionality is left incomplete here. -->
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Subcategory List :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="subCategoryList"
                 value="#{row.subCategory}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select"
                  itemValue="#{null}"/>

    <f:selectItems var="subCategory"
                   value="#{productManagedBean.getSubCategories(row.category)}"
                   itemLabel="#{subCategory.subCatName}"
                   itemValue="#{subCategory}"
                   rendered="true"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Brand (manufacturer) List :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="brandList"
                 value="#{row.brand}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select"
                  itemValue="#{null}"/>

    <f:selectItems var="brand"
                   value="#{productManagedBean.getBrands(row.category)}"
                   itemLabel="#{brand.brandName}"
                   itemValue="#{brand}"
                   rendered="true"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The managed bean (lazy data model can be ignored in the context of this question) :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ProductManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<Product> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    // Associated with <p:selectOneMenu id="categoryList">.
    private List<Category> categories; // Getter & setter.

    // These are merely helper maps to reduce possible database calls.
    private Map<Category, List<SubCategory>> subCategoriesByCategory;
    private Map<Category, List<Brand>> brandByCategory;

    public ProductManagedBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
         // This can be application scoped somewhere else as per business requirement.
        categories = service.getCatgeoryList();

        subCategoriesByCategory = new HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>();
        brandByCategory = new HashMap<Category, List<Brand>>();
    }

    // This method populates <f:selectItems> associated with <p:selectOneMenu id="brandList">.

    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories(Category category) {
        // category is never null here unless something is broken deliberately.

        if (category == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<SubCategory> subCategories = subCategoriesByCategory.get(category);

        if (subCategories == null) {
            subCategories = service.findSubCategoriesByCategoryId(category.getCatId());
            subCategoriesByCategory.put(category, subCategories);
        }

        return subCategories;
    }

    // This method populates <f:selectItems> associated with <p:selectOneMenu id="brandList">.
    public List<Brand> getBrands(Category category) {
        // category is never null here unless something is broken deliberately.

        if (category == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Brand> brands = brandByCategory.get(category);

        if (brands == null) {
            brands = service.findBrandsByCategoryId(category.getCatId());
            brandByCategory.put(category, brands);
        }

        return brands;
    }
}
```

In any case, the selected value in any of these menus is not supplied to the corresponding backing bean. It is only available in the model backed by JPA (`value="#{row.category}"`, `value="#{row.subCategory}"` and `value="#{row.brand}"` respectively).

► How to signal the backing bean that the first item with a `null`value (labelled "Select") in the parent menu is selected so as to resetting its child lists to empty? This should happen in any feasible way, if this is not feasible.

I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 final (community release) and Mojarra 2.2.12.

---

<sub>This is not needed unless there is a null foreign key in the underlying database table specifically using the vendor specific `ON DELETE SET NULL` option allowing an optional parent in each (or some) corresponding child row.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the point, you need to make sure that the `<f:selectItem>` getter is called with a `null` argument. In other words, the `#{row.category}` must be `null`. Given that you're for `#{row.category}` using the model als shown in this answer, [Populate p:selectOneMenu based on another p:selectOneMenu in each row of a p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613029/populate-pselectonemenu-based-on-another-pselectonemenu-in-each-row-of-a-pdat/23535806#23535806), most likely as below,

```
@Transient
private Category category;

public Category getCategory() {
    return (category == null && subCategory != null) ? subCategory.getCategory() : category;
}
```

then the `#{row.category}` will actually never be `null` when there's a `subCategory`. This will be the case when an existing data entry is presented in view.

You basically need to explicitly null out the `subCategory` (and `brand`) when the transient `category` property is explicitly set to null. This oversight has in the meanwhile been fixed in the mentioned answer. Here's how your new `setCategory()` method should look like:

```
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;

    if (category == null) {
        subCategory = null;
        brand = null;
    }
}
```

This way, the `getCategory()` will properly return `null` and thus the passed-in `#{row.category}` also.