# JSF/PrimeFaces associate item in a list using selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

In a JSF application I have a list of 3000 activities (JPA Entity Activity).  End users need to associate these activities in groups called jobs (JPA Entity Job). More than one user can claim an activity.

I'm trying to use a `p:selectOneMenu` on a datatable list to have the logged in user be able to tag activities to their JobId.

[image]

If Jones were logged in the select menu would have been set to 205 in the `Tag Your Job` column for the first activity.  If Smith were logged in the select and they selected 426 (menu would list only the job ids for Smith) in the `Tag Your Job` column, it would be added to the list in the `Associated Jobs` column.

I don't know how to wire this up. Here is my xhtml and entities.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="activity" 
    selection="#{activityAssociator.activitiesToAssociate}" rowKey="#{activity.an}" 
    value="#{activityAssociator.listOfActiveArtemisActivities}" filteredValue="#{activityAssociator.filteredActivities}">

<p:column headerText="Tag Your Job">
   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{activityAssociator.selectedJob}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" valueChangeListener="#{activityAssociator.listenTest1}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{activityAssociator.myAvailableJobs}" var="job" itemValue="job" itemLabel="#{job.jobId}" />
<p:ajax update="@form" listener="#{activityAssociator.listenTest2}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

### Activity Entity

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "artemisActivities")
private Collection<SupervisorJob> supervisorJobs;
```

### Job Entity

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "CTC_JOB_ACTIVITES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "jobId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "an"))
private Collection<ArtemisActivity> artemisActivities;
```

### EDIT

Based on BalusC's comment below, In the Activity Entity I added:

```
@Transient
private SupervisorJob myJob;
typical getter/setter
```

and this method in my backing bean, which is called from the @PostConstruct method

```
private void setSupervisorJob() {
    for (ArtemisActivity act : listOfActiveArtemisActivities) {
        for (SupervisorJob sj : act.getSupervisorJobs()) {
            if (sj.getJobOwner().equals(auth.getEmployee())) {
                act.setMyJob(sj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also modified the `<p:selectOneMenu` and changed to  `value="#{activity.myJob}"` 
The initial display of the datatable list now shows each selectonemenu correctly populated if applicable.  So that is good.

But how do I reference the Activity Id when I make a change to one of the row's select one menu?  I'm trying to do a JPA update/merge each time the job selectonemenu is changed on just that activity. Or Am I supposed to do a JPA update/merge on the whole 3000 entity collection every time. That seems overkill. Actually the datatable value `listOfActiveArtemisActivities` doesn't even reflect the changes based on the selections in the pull down when I iterate over it in my backing bean on during the listener event.

Comment: I believe you're looking for similar solution as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613029/populate-pselectonemenu-based-on-another-pselectonemenu-in-each-row-of-a-pdat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just missing the passing of the two Entities in my listener that I was trying to associate. `listener="#{bean.selectListener(activity, activity.myJob)}" />`

Along with the Edits listed above on the Transient field `myJob` here is the select one menu

```
<p:dataTable id="dt1" var="activity"  value="#{bean.list}" >
    <p:column headerText="Select">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{activity.myJob}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" var="job" itemValue="#{job}" itemLabel="#{job.jobId} - #{job.job_short_name} " />
            <p:ajax update="@form" listener="#{bean.selectListener(activity, activity.myJob)}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
   </p:column>
```